# Spring Security 4 - Get Authorization mappings

Tags: spring-security

Assuming I have a Spring Application whose requests are being authorized with http.authorizeRequests() and @PreAuthorize

Is there a way to get these mappings programmatically?
Is there an api within Spring where I can retrieve which urls are authorized for the currently authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there are better ways similar to we pass request header like @RequestHeader("Content-Type")... i would love to see that ...

```
@PreAuthorize("authorizeAccess(#user,#contentType,)")
public Idea somemethod(@RequestBody User user, @RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType )
{..}
```

But below is definitely an option.

Assuming you know how to write overrride or write your own methods to use in spring security  (customised class extending SecurityExpressionRoot). If so if you have a method i.e..authorizeAccess

```
public boolean authorizeAccess(String mapping)
{
  // use  mapping to authorize
  .. do something
}
```

Then, we can have all urls in a constant file..

```
package org.somepackage;
public interface URLMappings {
public static String ADMIN = "/admin";
}
```

Then pass these urls as constants ..

```
@RequestMapping(value = URLMappings.ADMIN, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize("authorizeAccess(T(org.somepackage.URLMappings).ADMIN)")
```